# php alphanumeric id with fixed letter position

Tags: php, mysql, alphanumeric, unique-id

I need to create unique alphanumeric IDs, 6 characters long in PHP.

Although I have found a lot of answers solving this problem, I would like the letters to be positioned in specific place in the ID, for example A1B2C3 (first, third and fifth character).

My only solution for this is to create 6 "for" loops (a-z and 0-9 * 3 times) and insert the output in an array and then in MySQL table. There will definitely be no duplicates but is there any better way?

My code so far is:

```
<?php

   $id=array();

   for($a='A';$a!='AA';$a++){
        for($b=1;$b<=9;$b++){
           for($c='A';$c!='AA';$c++){
              for($d=1;$d<=9;$d++){
                  for($e='A';$e!='AA';$e++){
                     for($f=1;$f<=9;$f++){

                       $id[]=$a.$b.$c.$d.$e.$f;
                     }
                  } 
              }
           }
        }
    }

    foreach ($id as $value) {
        echo "$value \n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: please include sample data, the code your have attempted so far and a dummy output of what the result you want should look like.

Comment: `unique` compared to what, the DB? Random solution, https://eval.in/591689, not unique though..

Comment: Updated my question with my code. The DB starts empty so unique as of the results created by my code. With the code above I get no duplicates but is this a good method of creating my ids?

Comment: How many IDs do you want to create at a time? Your code creates A LOT of IDs.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles at first I want 20.000 IDs but when those 20.000 are used, I want to continue from the ID I stopped+1. So I am considering that maybe I should first start by changing the last 4 digits and keep the first 2 static. When needed continue with the 2nd and 1st one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need sequential IDs:

```
// to start
//$numIds = 20000;
//$id = '';

// to add more
$numIds = 1000;
$id = 'A1J5M2'; // put MAX id from DB here

if ( '' !== $id ) { // increment id
  list($aa, $bb, $cc, $dd, $ee, $ff) = str_split($id);
  $arr = [$aa, $bb, $cc, $dd, $ee, $ff];
  list($aa, $bb, $cc, $dd, $ee, $ff) = incc($arr, count($arr) - 1);
}
else {
  list($aa, $bb, $cc, $dd, $ee, $ff) = ['A',1,'A',1,'A',1];
}

// generate ids    
$ids = [];

for($a=$aa;$a!='AA';$a++){
  for($b=$bb;$b<=9;$b++){
    $bb = 1; // reseting b - f is necessary when adding more ids
    for($c=$cc;$c!='AA';$c++){
      $cc = 'A';
      for($d=$dd;$d<=9;$d++){
        $dd = 1;
        for($e=$ee;$e!='AA';$e++){
          $ee = 'A';
          for($f=$ff;$f<=9;$f++){
            $ff = 1;

            $ids[] = "$a$b$c$d$e$f";
            // break out of all loops when desired number is reached
            if ( $numIds <= count($ids) ) { break 6; }
}}}}}}

// db setup
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbtest');
$insertstmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, 'INSERT INTO ids (id) VALUES (?)');

// insert ids
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertstmt, 's', $id);    
mysqli_autocommit($conn, false);
foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
  mysqli_stmt_execute($insertstmt);
}
mysqli_commit($conn);
mysqli_close($conn);


// function to increment given id, accommodates rolling over, e.g., A9 -> B1
function incc ($arr, $idx) {
  if ( is_int(intval($arr[$idx])) ) {
    if ( 9 == $arr[$idx] ) {
      $arr[$idx] = 1;
      $arr = incc($arr, --$idx); // recursing
    }
    else {
      $arr[$idx]++;
    }
  }
  else {
    if ( 'Z' === $arr[$idx] ) {
      $arr[$idx] = 'A';
      $arr = incc($arr, --$idx);
    }
    else {
      $ord = ord($arr[$idx]);
      $ord++;
      $arr[$idx] = chr($ord);
    }
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

[PHP Sandbox demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2205a6110554deb488a715bf621a0f9e00ab2843)

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. Problem solved. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For unique and random IDs, when you *don't need* sequential IDs:

```
$numIds = 20000; // how many ids do you want to generate and insert?

// db setup
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbtest');
$insertstmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, 'INSERT INTO ids (id) VALUES (?)');

// generate ids array
$ids = [];
for ($ii = 0; $ii < $numIds; $ii++) {
  do { // execute loop at least once

    // inspired by @chris85 's comment
    $id = randChr() . rand(0, 9) . randChr() . rand(0, 9) . randChr() . rand(0, 9);

  } while ( // try again if found in either db or array
    idInDb($conn, $id) || // not actually needed on first run
    (0 < count($ids) && in_array($id, $ids, true))
  );
  $ids[] = $id; // is unique, add to array
}

// insert ids
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertstmt, 's', $id);    
mysqli_autocommit($conn, false);
foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
  mysqli_stmt_execute($insertstmt);
}
mysqli_commit($conn);
mysqli_close($conn);


// helper functions

function randChr () { // generate random alpha character
  return chr(rand(65, 90)); // upper case only
  //return chr(rand(0, 1) ? rand(65, 90) : rand(97, 122));
  // use alternative return for upper AND lower case
}

function idInDB ($conn, $testid) { // check for id in db
  $query = "SELECT id FROM ids WHERE id = '$testid'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $found = 0 < mysqli_num_rows($result);
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  return $found;
}
```

[PHP Sandbox demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dbd8a2cb67dc82e3e5fba691cd52c04daff70b32)